# Supress circular-dependency warning for single files

Tags: angular, typescript, circular-dependency

I have some wanted circular dependencies in my code.
Let me provide a little example of what I mean.

**File a.ts**

```js
import {NAMES} from './b';

export class ClassA {
  constructor() { 
   console.log(NAMES);
  }
}
```

**File b.ts**

```js
import {ClassA} from './a';
import {nameOf} from './extensions';

export const NAMES = [nameOf(ClassA)];
```

This leads to a circular dependency warning. But ClassA is neither injected nor instanciated in the NAMES constant. So it seems legit.

I'm aware of the **showCircularDependencies** option. But I don't want to kick it off globally.

I've also tried the **include module** pattern:

**File include.ts**

```js
export {ClassA} from './a';
```

**File b.ts**

```js
import {ClassA} from './include';
import {nameOf} from './extensions';

export const NAMES = [nameOf(ClassA)];
```

But no success. Are there any other patterns that can help or is there a possibility to attach the showCircularDependencies option to just one file?

Comment: try using `export const NAMES = [nameof<ClassA>()]`

Answer (score 0):

Your file a.ts depends on b.ts and file b.ts depends on a.ts, which is the reason you are facing circular dependency warning.

There multiple ways to solve this warning.

One solution would to move the `NAMES` creation to a.ts and get rid of b.ts.

**a.ts:**

```
import {nameOf} from './extensions';
export class ClassA {
  constructor() { 
    console.log(NAMES);
  }
}
const NAMES = nameOf(ClassA);
```

As object of `ClassA` will be initiated after the line `const NAMES = nameOf(ClassA);` is executed, the constructor of `classA` would have correct value in `NAMES` constant